# How do I exclude a git submodule from update using python?

Tags: python, git

When I run the following command from a bash shell, it works as expected, and updates all submodules except the one indicated as to-be-ignored:

```
git -c submodule."MySub".update=none submodule update --init --recursive
```

However, when I attempt the same thing in python using subprocess, MySub gets updated as well:

```
cmd = ['git', '-c', 'submodule."MySub".update=none', 'submodule', 'update', '--init', '--recursive']

subprocess.call(cmd)
```

Do I need to format the `'submodule."MySub".update=none'` argument differently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In bash you can use the quotes for special characters in the submodule path (slashes for example), but in python you don't need them. Try it with:

```
'submodule.MySub.update=none'
```